# Ошибка reached end of file while parsing }

Tags: java

Здравствуйте, начинаю изучать java по книге Head First - Java. понимаю что вопрос наверно детский, но у меня вылетает эта ошибка, и я не знаю в чём проблема, вроде скобки расставлены правильно, но она всё равно вылетает, Подскажите пожалуйста.

```
public class MovieTestDrive {
  public static void main (String[] args) {
    Movie one = new Movie();
    one.title = "Inception";
    one.genre = "Army";
    one.rating = 8;
    Movie two = new Movie();
    two.title = "The race";
    two.genre = "Arcade";
    two.rating = 6;
    two.playIt
  }
}

class Movie {
 String title;
 String genre;
 int rating;

 void playIt() {
    System.out.println("Проигрывание Фильма");
 }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

При вызове, как и при объявлении, метода **обязательно** нужно использовать скобки, даже если метод не принимает ни одного параметра. А после каждого оператора должна следовать точка с запятой.

Таким образом, вместо

> `two.playIt`

нужно писать

```
two.playIt();
```

Comment: да, вы правы, что то я это пропустил. Сейчас изменил, но всё равно та же самая ошибка.

Comment: @AntonBarinov код весь привели?

Comment: @AntonBarinov У меня Ваш код, после исправлений, работает

Comment: Спасибо, разораблся