# Почему тут не работает код?

Tags: java

Прошу помочь не понимаю в чем дело пишет: Main.java:31: error: reached end of file while parsing. И так во всех программах!

```
/* package whatever; // don't place package name! */

import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

/* Name of the class has to be "Main" only if the class is public. */
class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {        System.out.print("Наименьшие числа в шеснадцатиричной системе: ");

            int a = 0xA;
            int b = 0x22;
            int c = 0x41;

            System.out.println(Math.min(Math.min(a, b), c));

            int q = 0x4C;
            int d = 0x22;
            int e = 0x41;

            System.out.println(Math.min(Math.min(q, d), e));

            int w = 0xB;
            int r = 0x4B;
            int t = 0x14;

            System.out.println(Math.min(Math.min(w, r), t));

}
```

Comment: добавьте в конце еще одну `}`

Comment: раньше код полностью работал, а сейчас не может

Comment: Вы удалили закрывающую `}`, которая "раньше" там была

Comment: посмотрите в словаре как пишется слово "шеснадцатиричной"

Comment: да правильно я написал айдия ругается и пишет это: Error:(30, 6) java: reached end of file while parsing

Comment: а код который на иде оне работает

Comment: я не понимаю, что Вы пишете. Если Вы написали "правильно", тогда о чем вопрос?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/610431/%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-reached-end-of-file-while-parsing

Answer (score 3):

Нужно добавить потерянную фигурную скобку в предпоследней строке. Должно получиться вот так:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

class Ideone {
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {            
        System.out.print("Наименьшие числа в шеснадцатиричной системе: ");

        int a = 0xA;
        int b = 0x22;
        int c = 0x41;

        System.out.println(Math.min(Math.min(a, b), c));

        int q = 0x4C;
        int d = 0x22;
        int e = 0x41;

        System.out.println(Math.min(Math.min(q, d), e));

        int w = 0xB;
        int r = 0x4B;
        int t = 0x14;

        System.out.println(Math.min(Math.min(w, r), t));
    }
}
```