# Что значит ошибка: reached end of file while parsing }

Tags: java

```
public class HexStringConverter
{    
    public static String[] hexStrings = {"2ae43", "8g023", "249abc", "2354aer23", "234245"};введите сюда код
    public static void main (String [] args)
    {
        //given variables

        char[] hexCharArray = hexStrings[0].toCharArray();

        //define the allowed characters (hex alphabet) and print them out
char [] HexAlphabet={'a','b','c','d','e','f','0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'};
System.out.print(" Zugelassene Hex-Alphabet Zeichen:");
for (int i = 0; i< HexAlphabet.length; i = i + 1 )
{
System.out.print(HexAlphabet[i]+"  ");
}

        //auxiluary variables
boolean STRING=true;
boolean CHAR=false;
long R=0;
for( int a=0; a<hexStrings.length;a=a+1)
{
hexCharArray=hexStrings[a].toCharArray();
STRING=true;
R=0;

            //check if the string contains only valid HEX-Value-signs
        for(int b=0; b<hexCharArray.length;b=b+1)
        {
            STRING=false;
            for(int c=0; c<HexAlphabt.length;c=c+1)
            {
                if(hexCharArray[b]==HexAlphabet[c])
                CHAR=true;
            }
            if(!CHAR)
            {
                STRING=false;
            }
        }
            //if valid calculate decimal value
            // calculation of powers (Hochzahlen) is done with Math.pow(double a, double b) method.
            // e.g. Math.pow(16,0) --> 1 or Math.pow( 16,2) --> 256
            if(STRING)
            {
                int PLATZ=0;
                for(int b=hexCharArray.length-1;b>=0;b=b-1)
                {
                    for(int c=0; c<HexAlphabet;c=c+1)
                    {
                        if(hexCharArray[b]==HexAlphabet[k])
                        {
                            R=R+c*(int)Math.pow(16,PLATZ);
                            PLATZ=PLATZ+1;
                        }
                    }
                }
                System.out.println("Der Dezimalwert des Hex-Strings "+hexStrings[a]+" ist "+R);
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Der String "+ hexStrings[a]+", ist kein gueltiger Hex-String.");
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: скорее всего `}`. Если отформатируешь код, то увидишь что где не хватает

Comment: Заголовок должен содержать краткую суть проблемы, а не абстрактное "помогите, все пропало" ...

Answer (score 0):

Вот [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/610431/216510) похожий вопрос. Ответ кроется в вашем методе `main(){}` как уже подметил @Grundy

А именно, вы закрыли класс `}` а вот метод `main` не закрыли.

Добавьте в самом конце кода еще 1 `}`