# ошибка при подключение телефона Pixel2 xl к андроид студии

Tags: android, android-studio

Вот сама ошибка,Студия телефон видит,на скриншоте вроде видно,при запуске условного проекта вот такая вот ошибка
[image: введите сюда описание изображения] 
C:\Users\SONY\AndroidStudioProjects\TestProject2\app\src\main\java\com\example\testproject\MainActivity.java:13: error: reached end of file while parsing
    }

---

Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug] in project C:\Users\SONY\AndroidStudioProjects\TestProject2

> Task :app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :app:generateDebugBuildConfig
>   Task :app:javaPreCompileDebug
>   Task :app:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
>   Task :app:compileDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
>   Task :app:mainApkListPersistenceDebug
>   Task :app:generateDebugResValues
>   Task :app:generateDebugResources
>   Task :app:createDebugCompatibleScreenManifests
>   Task :app:extractDeepLinksDebug
>   Task :app:processDebugManifest
>   Task :app:mergeDebugShaders
>   Task :app:compileDebugShaders
>   Task :app:generateDebugAssets
>   Task :app:mergeDebugAssets
>   Task :app:mergeDebugResources
>   Task :app:processDebugResources
>
> Task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED
>   C:\Users\SONY\AndroidStudioProjects\TestProject2\app\src\main\java\com\example\testproject\MainActivity.java:13: error: reached end of file while parsing
>       }
>        ^
>   1 error

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

  > Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 31s
13 actionable tasks: 13 executed

The build scan was not published due to a configuration problem.

The Gradle Terms of Service have not been agreed to.

For more information, please see https://gradle.com/scans/help/plugin-terms-of-service.

Alternatively, if you are using Gradle Enterprise, specify the server location.
For more information, please see https://gradle.com/scans/help/plugin-enterprise-config.

Comment: Думаю поможет https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/610431/Ошибка-reached-end-of-file-while-parsing

Comment: Спасибо,я уже просто намучился с VD-x что не заметил простейшую ошибку)))

Answer (score 0):

Студия говорит что в MainActivity.java ошибка на строке 13. Возможно ты не поставил точку с запятой